# How to send html page as content of nodemailer

Tags: node.js

In my application i'm using nodemailer to send an email.
i want send html page content(have some info) to recipients

how to do that? Please anyone help me

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is read the HTML file using fs module in node and then
replace the elements that you want to be changed in the HTML string using
handlebars

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var fs = require('fs');

var readHTMLFile = (path, callback) => {
  fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    else {
      return callback(null, html);
    }
  });
};

smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  host: mailConfig.host,
  secure: mailConfig.secure,
  port: mailConfig.port,
  auth: {
    user: mailConfig.auth.user,
    pass: mailConfig.auth.pass
  }
}));

readHTMLFile(__dirname + 'app/public/pages/emailWithPDF.html', function (err, html) {
  var template = handlebars.compile(html);
  var replacements = {
    username: "John Doe"
  };
  var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'my@email.com',
            to : 'some@email.com',
            subject : 'test subject',
            html : htmlToSend
         };
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response)=> {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                callback(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Raj thanks for your reply what is the value 
    **host**,
    **secure**,
    **port**:

Comment: Hi raj it take static html page can we do dynamic page also ?

Comment: i want change content of html page dynamically how to achieve ? let me know please

Comment: @veda Please refer this https://www.codementor.io/joshuaaroke/sending-html-message-in-nodejs-express-9i3d3uhjr